# MS ACCESS DLOOKUP How to deal with error on return data?

Tags: ms-access, null

I have a list of items, some of which have an order ident (`nvarchar`) related to them.
I wish to display the items in the list and use `DLookup` to display the order numbers, if appropriate.
This works, however if there is no order ident then it displays +Error

My control source for the field is:

```
=DLookUp("[PONumber]","[Q_SalesOrders_CustomerDetails]","[OrderID]=" & [OrderID])
```

What I suspect is happening is that, since there is no Order related to the item then the `OrderID` (`integer`) is null therefore it can't return anything for the `POnumber` (`nvarchar`)

Can I get it to translate this as "n/a" in the `PONumber` field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `DLookup`, you need `IIf` for the two cases:

```
= IIf([OrderID] IS Null, "n/a", 
      DLookUp("[PONumber]","[Q_SalesOrders_CustomerDetails]","[OrderID]=" & [OrderID])
```

---

But using `DLookup` in a continuous form isn't always the best idea.

You could try using a LEFT JOIN as recordsource of your form, so that PONumber becomes available as source field.

Something like this (if `Q_Items` is the original recordsource of your form):

```sql
SELECT Q_Items.*, Nz(Q_SalesOrders_CustomerDetails.PONumber, "n/a") AS PO_Number
FROM Q_Items LEFT JOIN Q_SalesOrders_CustomerDetails
  ON Q_Items.OrderID = Q_SalesOrders_CustomerDetails.OrderID
```